# CSV File not being downloaded from Umbraco

Tags: c#, csv, fiddler, umbraco7

I've set up for a CSV file to be downloaded when a button is clicked, I'm using AngularJS and C# for Umbraco. I'm building an Umbraco plugin, the point is to export all the dictionary keys. I'm selecting them from the database and placing them within a list with the type Item (pulled from a model). The issue I'm having is that I'm not getting any errors however the browser isn't downloading the CSV.

```
//ExportDictionaryAllController.cs
//This is where I am telling the browser to download the csv file.

using UmbracoImportExportPlugin.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Text;
using Umbraco.Core.Persistence;
using Umbraco.Web;
using Umbraco.Web.WebApi;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace UmbracoImportExportPlugin.App_Code
{
    public class ExportDictionaryAllController : UmbracoAuthorizedApiController
    {
        [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public void ExportAll()
        {
            List<Item> DictionaryItems = new List<Item>();
            DictionaryItems = getList();
            string attachment = "attachment; filename= DictionaryItems.csv;";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", attachment);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");
            WriteColumnName();
            foreach (Item item in DictionaryItems)
            {

                WriteItemInfo(item);
            }
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }

        private void WriteItemInfo(Item item)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            AddComma(item.Key, sb);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }

        private void AddComma(string value, StringBuilder sb)
        {
            sb.Append(value.Replace(',', ' '));
            sb.Append(", ");
        }

        private void WriteColumnName()
        {
            string columnNames = "Key, English, Hebrew, Russian";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(columnNames);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }

        public List<Item> getList()
        {
            UmbracoDatabase db = ApplicationContext.DatabaseContext.Database;
            var select = new Sql("SELECT [key] FROM cmsDictionary;");
            List<Item> DictionaryItems = new List<Item>();
            DictionaryItems = db.Fetch<Item>(select);
            return DictionaryItems;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain to me why no errors or exceptions are being returned, I'm also using Fiddler which is telling me the header is returning:

Entity

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= DictionaryItems.csv
Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8
```

In the Raw tab I see the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Pragma: public
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= DictionaryItems.csv;
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?YzpcdXNlcnNcam9uYXRoYW4uYXZyYWhhbVxkb2N1bWVudHNcdmlzdWFsIHN0dWRpbyAyMDEzXFByb2plY3RzXFVtYnJhY29JbXBvcnRFeHBvcnRQbHVnaW5cVW1icmFjb0ltcG9ydEV4cG9ydFBsdWdpblx1bWJyYWNvXGJhY2tvZmZpY2VcYXBpXEV4cG9ydERpY3Rpb25hcnlBbGxcRXhwb3J0QWxs?=
Date: Wed, 20 Apr 2016 12:13:45 GMT

94
Key, English, Hebrew, Russian
submit_button, 
form_button, 
hello_button, 
world_button, 
sublime_button, 
bootstrap_button, 
this_button, 

0
```

Comment: I think the issue is with HTTP/1.1 and chunked combined.  A few weeks ago I had same issue and compared results from IE with my c# code.  Found that IE used HTTP/1.0 which eliminated the chunked mode.  The Net library doesn't work properly with chunked.  There are lots of discussion on this on the web.

Comment: So if I used IE browser, it would potentially work?

Comment: @jdweng, how did you sort out the issue and export a csv file then?

Comment: Change header in request to HTTP/1.0.  It has to be done in the initial request. request.ProtocolVersion = System.Net.HttpVersion.Version10;

Comment: Not exactly sure how to do this. When I put that line in the code I get the following error: ** 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage' does not contain a definition for 'ProtocolVersion' and no extension method 'ProtocolVersion' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Comment: Request message is child of a Request.  What code are using to make the initial connection (usually using Create() method)? The Create method returns the Request where you need to modify the headers.  You are getting a 200 OK (not 200 Done).  OK indicates there is more data to download in chunks.  Setting HTTP/1.0 should eliminate the chunks and you should get the data in a stream.  Use a IE and capture results with fiddler.  Then modify your headers to look like the IE results.  Adding headers like you are doing in the response probably won't work.  You need to add headers to initial request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this with my angular-js controller by adding:

`window.open(downloadUrl, "_blank");`

to the angular controller - ExportAllController.

it shouldn't have been necessary but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Do something similar to this

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public FileResult Download()
{
    var csv = new List<string>();
    csv.Add("Key, English, Hebrew, Russian");

    //add items as string seperated by commas to csv 

    MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(mstream);

    foreach (var row in csv)
    {
            sw.Write(row);
    }

    sw.Flush();
    mstream.Position = 0;
    byte[] contents = new byte[mstream.Length];
    mstream.Read(contents, 0, (int)mstream.Length);

    return File(contents, "text/csv", "DictionaryItems.csv");
}
```

Comment: Everytime I do it tells me that I'm using File as a variable not as a type.